# Translation of data during import

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing approx 350,000 lines from a CSV file into MySQL using PHP (Symfony Framework if that matters) I am reading in each line and inserting into the SQL table as I go. This will be a daily process - and the number of lines will increase.

I have to translate 2 of the columns to a number (which is a foreign key). I want to know the most efficient way of doing it. I am experimenting with using a lookup table in MySQL and also an array in PHP - but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way.

There are approx 60 different combinations the 2 columns could be, here is an example of the translation table I have

```
Feature         Type          CODE
ANZIRL          Voice Call    8
BT2DT2          Data Call     6
BT2IL2          Voice Call    1
BT2UK2          Voice Call    2
DG2DG2          Voice Call    4
DG2DT2          Data Call     3
DG2EC           Voice Call    1
DG2EDQ          Voice Call    5
DG2EZY          Voice Call    7
```

And the CSV will be as follows

```
DG2DG2,x,x,x,Voice Call,x,x
DG2DT2,x,x,x,Data Call,x,x
```

etc...

I need to insert that into my table as

```
x,4,x,x
x,3,x,x
```

etc ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would batch import the CSV file into MySQL as is (i.e. create a table that mirrors CSV field layout), and then run a query against the CSV import table to get the foreign key code.

Something like:

```
INSERT into sometable (code,other,fields)
SELECT code, other, fields
FROM codes c
JOIN csvtable ct
WHERE ct.feature = c.feature AND ct.type = c.type
```

Basic idea is to not perform processing on row-by-row basis in PHP or MySQL, but to get all the data into MySQL and then run some version of above query to efficiently do the foreign key translation in 1-step.

If you go row-by-row with 350,000+ records, that will be a fairly slow process, php is not terribly efficient...

Comment: OK - thats a different approach - thanks ... there approx 40 columns in the CSV and I only need 8 - but might be faster this way.

Comment: Not might, it will without exception be faster. Don't worry about number of the columns imported, the size of the table is not important at this scale, but offloading processing to MySQL from relatively inefficient PHP/Symphony is, very important.  Give it a try: first hold your breath; then row-by-row import 350,000 records into MySQL with Symphony; once it's completed, take breath again ;--)

Comment: awesome, see you would have died if you tried option #1 (and my suggestion to hold your breath) ;--)